# AD, BE CF are concurrent lines in triangle ABC. EF, FD ,DE meet BC,CA,AB at X,Y,Z

Tags: geometry

AD,BE and CF are three concurrent lines meeting the sides BC,CA,AB in D,E,F .suppose EF, FD and DE meet BC,CA,AB at X,Y,Z .prove that B,C divide DX harmonically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent, by Ceva we have:
$$\frac{\overrightarrow{AF}}{\overrightarrow{FB}}\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{BD}}{\overrightarrow{DC}}\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{CE}}{\overrightarrow{EA}}=1.$$
Since $E,F,X$ are collinear, by Menelaus we have:
$$\frac{\overrightarrow{AF}}{\overrightarrow{FB}}\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{BX}}{\overrightarrow{XC}}\cdot \frac{\overrightarrow{CE}}{\overrightarrow{EA}}=-1.$$
By dividing these:
$$\frac{\overrightarrow{BD}}{\overrightarrow{DC}}:\frac{\overrightarrow{BX}}{\overrightarrow{XC}}=-1,$$
so $\mathcal H(D,X;B,C)$.