# Prove that $X,Y,Z$ are collinear.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

> $AD,BE$ and $CF$ are three concurrent lines meeting the sides $BC,CA,AB$ in $D,E,F$. Suppose $EF,FD$ and $DE$ meet $BC,CA,AB$ at $X,Y,Z$. Prove that $B,C$ divide $DX$ harmonically and $X,Y,Z$ are collinear.

**What I Tried**:- Here is a Figure :-

[image]

I have the answer of the first part here, which is understandable :- [AD, BE CF are concurrent lines in triangle ABC. EF, FD ,DE meet BC,CA,AB at X,Y,Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918678/ad-be-cf-are-concurrent-lines-in-triangle-abc-ef-fd-de-meet-bc-ca-ab-at-x-y)

Now the second part I think, is also easy, which I need to show by the Converse of Menelaus Theorem, but in these type of problems I usually get confused with the side-lengths. As far as I could decide, to show $X,Y,Z$ are collinear I need to show :=

$$\frac{AY}{CY} * \frac{BZ}{AZ} * \frac{CX}{AX} = -1.$$

Is this correct? Someone Please Confirm.

I also have no idea how to show this claim. I tried in some particular ways, but it didn't work.

Can someone guide me through this problem?

Comment: you need to rename the points in the diagram or in question. They are not in sync. Also you can start from any point, but it is easier to choose a point that you can keep as pivot. Btw it seems somewhat similar to a question you asked a few days earlier.

Comment: @MathLover I forgot to do that, but I have a figure in my Copy =).

Comment: I did ask 1 type of Question like this before, but I always confuse the lengths which involve collinearity with Menelaus Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are on side $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ respectively. By Menelaus' Theorem, they are collinear iff $\frac {BX}{XC}\cdot \frac {CY}{YA} \cdot \frac {AZ}{BZ}=1$

Applying Ceva's Theorem on $\triangle ABC$ gives,

$\frac {BD}{DC}\cdot \frac {CE}{EA} \cdot \frac {AF}{FB}=1$

Applying Menelaus'  theorem on $\triangle ABC$ considering $FEX$ as the transversal gives,

$\frac {BD}{DC}\cdot \frac {CE}{EA} \cdot \frac {AZ}{BZ}=1$

Similarly,  applying Menelaus'  theorem on $\triangle ABC$ considering $FDY$ and $DEZ$ as transversal respectively gives,

$\frac {CE}{EA}\cdot \frac {AF}{FB} \cdot \frac {BX}{XC}=1$

$\frac {AF}{FB}\cdot \frac {BD}{DC} \cdot \frac {CY}{YA}=1$

Multiplying these three equations and then following Ceva's  Theorem gives the desired result.

$\frac {CE}{EA}\cdot \frac {AF}{FB} \cdot \frac {BX}{XC}=1$

$\Rightarrow \frac {BX}{XC}=\frac {BD}{DC}$ by Ceva's Theorem and thereafter points $D$,  $X$ divide $BC$ harmonically. So do points $F$, $Z$ and $E$, $Y$ to sides $AB$ and $CA$ respectively.

Comment: I got it thank you, this does the problem quite nicely, both the parts.